# Spark bean encoder for Java classes extending com.sun.jna.Structure

Tags: java, apache-spark, jna

I'm running some native code from within a Spark UDF using JNA. Currently I map those manually on Scala Case-Classes to be returned from the UDF (schema is inferred automatically). This leads to much code duplication, as the data-structures are almost identical.

So I declared a bunch of Java Classes to map the native datastructures (those classes need to inherit from `com.sun.jna.Structure`), they look like:

```
public class MyStruct extends com.sun.jna.Structure {

  public double[] cp_O = new double[3];
  public int B_HN;
  public double B_Yo;
  public double B_DY;

  @Override
  protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("cp_O","B_HN","B_Yo","B_DY");
}
```

}

Next, to use `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean`, I added getter and setter for this class (to make it a bean) and tried :

```
implicit val encoder = Encoders.bean(classOf[MyStruct])

// dummy udf without native call, just return a Bean
val myUDF = udf(() => new MyStruct(),encoder.schema)

ss.range(1)
  .withColumn("result",myUDF())
  .show()
```

This gives:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:465)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:89)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:142)

If I remove the `extends Structure` from my class, the code runs fine for spark, but not for JNA. So apparently `Structure` adds many fields to `MyStruct`, one of them are not supported/cannot be mapped. As I don't need those fields anyway, how can I formulate my code such that only "my" fields in `MyStruct` are encoded, but not those inherited from `Structure`?

Comment: I suggest you cross-post this question to the [JNA mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jna-users) to get more visibility.